# Can't unlock a users changes in TFS . The tf commands are timing out

Tags: tfs

I've had a user mark the entire dev branch for deletion, they then attempted to revert / undo these changes but it just hangs. There are 14 million items stuck in their pending changes.
All of the tf undo, tf remove workspace, commands time out. Is there anyway to remove the lock that is preventing other users from checking in their code?

I can see the PendingChanges for that user in the TFS database but don't know if I can just remove them or what other tables hold the Locks?

Comment: Have you tried using `tf undo $/Project/SomeFolder` so that it's not trying to do 14 million undo's at a time?

Comment: Yes, I tried to undo individual projects and items at the bottom levels of the tree, it still just locks. Don't see the pending changes in TFS sidekicks either. Users machine is just hanging when he tries to goto the repository.

Comment: If you change the TFS databases directly you invalidate your warranty and support agreement for your TFS server. Don't ever make changes directly, call support.

Comment: Do you run tf undo command on TFS server? (remove pending changes in a remove workspace: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/undo-command)

Answer (score 0):

For the timeout exception, you could update the `tf.exe.config` or `devenv.exe.config` file with the following configuration values:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
        <add address="*" maxconnection="1000"/>
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

After set the limit to 1000 on your side, then try to  undo individual projects  like *jessehouwing* suggested, also keep watching the value in Resource Monitor,.